# Create new variables/class instances inside for-loop? Python web scraping

Tags: python, loops, class, object, web-scraping

I am currently working on a web scraper that will take urls as inputs, find the page, scrape it, then return results in a CSV. The scraper works well for single URL's at a time. But unfortunately whenever it writes a new line to the scrape results CSV it also appends the previous url's scrape results in each column. I need a loop that will essentially create new class variables inside the loop so that this doesn't happen. Something like that does this: Takes list of urls, then also creates unique class instance.

```
links = ['www.SomeLink1.com','www.Somelink2.com','www.SomeLink3.com']


person1 = Person('www.SomeLink1.com', driver = driver, close_on_complete = False)
person2 = Person('www.Somelink2.com', driver = driver, close_on_complete = False)
person3 = Person('www.SomeLink3.com', driver = driver, close_on_complete = False)
```

I do not have access to the source code to create a new method "person1.reset()" or something.

Here is also the original code I was using to scrape multiple pages:

```
# Import libraries
from linkedin_scraper import Person, actions
from selenium import webdriver
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import smtplib

# Read-in list of contacts:
contacts = pd.read_csv("/Users/Desktop/ContactList.csv")
names = contacts['contact_name'].tolist()
urls = contacts['contact_url'].tolist()
# turn contacts list into dictionary just in case
contact_dict = {names[i]: urls[i] for i in range(len(names))}
print(contact_dict)

# automatically login to LinkedIn
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Downloads/chromedriver')
email = os.environ.get('LINKEDIN_USER')
password = os.environ.get('LINKEDIN_PASS')
actions.login(driver, email, password)

# create general field names
fields = ['name', 'about', 'job_title', 'location','company',
          'education','accomplishments','linkedin_url']

with open('ScrapeResults.csv', 'w') as f:
    # using csv.writer method from CSV package
    write = csv.writer(f)
    write.writerow(fields)
f.close()

# Loop-through urls to scrape multiple pages at once
for individual,link in contact_dict.items():

    ## assign ##
    the_name = individual
    the_link = link
    # scrape peoples url:
    person = Person(the_link, driver=driver, close_on_complete=False)

    # rows to be written... only index for lists?
    rows = [[person.name, person.about, person.job_title, person.location, person.company,
             person.educations, person.accomplishments, person.linkedin_url]]
    # write
    with open('ScrapeResults.csv', 'a') as f:
    # using csv.writer method from CSV package
        write = csv.writer(f)
        write.writerows(rows)
        f.close()
```

Comment: Or is there any way to reset the person = Person(the_link, driver=driver, close_on_complete=False) in this for-loop without having to actually edit the source code for the package?

Comment: Or, it could be that your `rows` variable is accumulating results from previous runs, so each time you write `rows` you are writing accumulated results.

Comment: @RazzleShazl Yes that's exactly what's happening. The results are accumulating/appending in the class attributes every time the for-loop iterates.

Comment: I think the results are accumulating within the driver, so it in turn produces accumulating results in `rows`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you change to `close_on_complete=True`?  I don't know what it does, but it seems like that might help reset `Person`.

Comment: ```close_oncomplete = True``` Just closes the page after the scrape is complete. The attributes such as name, company, job, location, etc. are still stored in Person object. @user212514

Comment: I wonder if you might find something useful by inspecting the class itself, like `print(Person.__dict__.keys())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got in touch with creator of "linkedin_scraper" library. He fixed a bug that cached previous linkedin profile values/accumulated them when scraping multiple at once.

Issue resolved in version 2.7.5.

Please see: https://github.com/joeyism/linkedin_scraper/issues/84

Thanks all!

Comment: Weird I cannot find the issue in their [closed issues](https://github.com/joeyism/linkedin_scraper/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed) or [open issues](https://github.com/joeyism/linkedin_scraper/issues).  I mean there are only 5 closed and 5 open issues in 2021 and none fit the description here.

Comment: Since SO if a Q&A format site geared towards helping future readers who might have the same issue, could you elaborate on your self-accepted answer and provide a bit more information?  For example, where is this issue tracked?  When will the fix roll out?  This "answer" leaves readers hanging.

Comment: Looking at their [releases](https://pypi.org/project/linkedin-scraper/#history), their latest release was on March 9, one day after you posted this issue on March 8.  Did the March 9 release fix this issue?

Comment: That's correct! Sorry for confusion @RazzleShazl... see updated answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Could you try instantiating a new `driver` each time?  That should reset counters in `driver` for you.

```
for individual,link in contact_dict.items():
    the_name = individual
    the_link = link
    driver = Driver() # I don't know how to instantiate this
    person = Person(the_link, driver=driver, close_on_complete=False).
```

Without access to driver documentation, I cannot speak to how to properly instantiate it.  As well, it might even have a helper to `clear()` or `reset()` internal variables which would be preferable to recreating the `driver` from scratch.  In any case, the scraper should have straightforward documentation for this.

Comment: I'll create a class Driver() and try instantiating it each iteration of the loop as you showed above.

Comment: `Driver()` is a guess -- can you find in your code where `driver` is instantiated?  Then reuse that.